# postgresql simple select is slow

Tags: postgresql

i have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('seq_my_table_id'::regclass),
  fk_id1 integer NOT NULL,
  fk_id2 smallint NOT NULL,
  name character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  description text,
  currency_name character varying(3) NOT NULL,
  created timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  updated timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  CONSTRAINT "PK_my_table_id" PRIMARY KEY (id ),
  CONSTRAINT "FK_my_table_fk_id1" FOREIGN KEY (fk_id1)
      REFERENCES my_table2 (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
  CONSTRAINT "FK_my_table_fk_id2" FOREIGN KEY (fk_id2)
      REFERENCES my_table3 (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE,
  autovacuum_enabled=true,
  autovacuum_vacuum_threshold=50,
  autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor=0.2,
  autovacuum_analyze_threshold=50,
  autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor=0.1,
  autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay=20,
  autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit=200,
  autovacuum_freeze_min_age=50000000,
  autovacuum_freeze_max_age=200000000,
  autovacuum_freeze_table_age=150000000
);
ALTER TABLE my_table
  OWNER TO postgres;

CREATE INDEX my_table_fk_id1
  ON my_table
  USING btree
  (fk_id1 );

CREATE INDEX my_table_fk_id2
  ON my_table
  USING btree
  (fk_id2 );
```

tables records count

```
select count(id) from my_table; --24061
select count(id) from my_table2; --24061
select count(id) from my_table3; --123
```

execution time

```
select * from my_table -- ~17sec
```

`vacuum/analyze` - no effect 
`description` - length ~ 4000 chars in each row

`postgres.conf` - standart settings

Version: `9.1`

select all fields except description reduce execution time to ~1,5 sec

How to icrease select speed with description ?

## upd

```
--explain analyze select * from my_table
"Seq Scan on my_table (cost=0.00..3425.79 rows=24079 width=1015) (actual time=0.019..17.238 rows=24079 loops=1)"
"Total runtime: 18.649 ms"
```

Comment: Which application are you using to display the result of the `select *` statement? Which runtime is reported for `explain analyze select * from my_table`

Comment: `select *` just example, but `select fk_id1, fk_id2, name, currency_name, description` - uses ( same 17 sec ), also see question update

Comment: The runtime **on the server** is only 18 **milli** seconds (18.649ms). That means if your frontend takes 17 *seconds* the time is lost sending the rows over the network (or inside the client application)

Comment: If the length of one row with the description field included is about 4000 bytes and there are about 24000 rows, the client has to retrieve 24k times 4k=96 megabytes. Spending 17s on this means that the client/network is processing data at 45 MBits/s (note:bits, not bytes). It's not unreasonable if this is a 100Mbits/s network.

Comment: It's a rare case that it makes sense to retrieve `all 24k rows`. Indexes are utterly useless for such a case. If you want to speed up the operation, add an adequate `WHERE` clause to only select the data you need. Indexes may help with *that*.

Comment: @Daniel Vérité This happens on localhost and i cannot understand reason why so little volume of data takes so long time

Comment: @Erwin Brandstetter where/limit etc its a stubs. I want to know why postgres so slowly, for example on sql-server this query took < 1 sec. May be exists some server settings to improve speed ?

Comment: Something you might want to check is that ssl is turned off for localhost connections (try `show ssl` in psql)

Comment: @cetver: Of course, general performance tuning always helps. Standard installations come with minimal settings in many distributions. Have a look at the [Postgres Wiki](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server).

Answer (score 1):

The question is how to make this fast.  The issue is not on the server since it takes 18ms there.  The simple solution is to select fewer columns so that there is less to transfer over the network.  My guess is that you have long descriptions on some.  Leave that column off your select and try again.